# Google Maps in React don't show multiple markers

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-markers, react-google-maps

I have a problem. I have the array markers that is populated by my backend in the correct way, because after the call I will have an array with this format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Via Noberto Rosa 13, Torino, 10154",
        "position": {
            "lat": 45.089546,
            "lng": 7.7135392
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Via pessinetto 12, Torino, 10149",
        "position": {
            "lat": 45.09009409999999,
            "lng": 7.659178599999999
        }
    }
]
```

How is it that when I load the map, I don’t see any markers? I happened to see something once, maybe it’s an asynchronous call problem? Also the map, sometimes, does not fit well with the latitude and longitude I gave her, maybe it is a problem that is solved once the markers are rendered correctly. How do you do that?

**I dont want use React.useState() because i want avoid re-rendering of the page to make as few calls as possible to the Google Apis.**

**Map.js:**

```js
/* eslint-disable no-undef */ 
import React from "react"; 
import { GoogleMap, Marker } from "@react-google-maps/api"; 
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

Geocode.setApiKey("xxxxxxxxxx"); 
Geocode.setLanguage("it"); 
Geocode.setRegion("it"); 
Geocode.setLocationType("ROOFTOP"); 
Geocode.enableDebug();

const markers = [];

function Map() {   const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };

  async function getAddresses() {
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/maps/allResults", requestOptions);
    let addresses = await response.json();
    Object.keys(addresses).forEach(async function (key) {
        let response = await Geocode.fromAddress(addresses[key]['indirizzo'] + ", " + addresses[key]['citta'] + ", " + addresses[key]['cap']);
        const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
        markers.push({"id": addresses[key]['id'], "name": addresses[key]['indirizzo'] + ", " + addresses[key]['citta'] + ", " + addresses[key]['cap'], "position": {"lat": lat, "lng": lng}})
    }) }

  getAddresses()   .catch(err => console.log(err));

  console.log(markers)

  const handleOnLoad = (map) => {
    const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    markers.forEach(({ position }) => bounds.extend(position));
    map.fitBounds(bounds);   };

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      onLoad={handleOnLoad}
      center={{lat: 45.116177, lng: 7.742615}}
      mapContainerStyle={{ height: "100%", display: "flex" }}
    >
      {markers.map(({ id, name, position }) => (
        <Marker
        key={id}
        name={name}
        position={position}
        >
        </Marker>
      ))}
    </GoogleMap>   ); }

export default Map;
```

Answer (score -1):

To display multiple markes all you have to do is iterate in a array with the marks positions.

```
{marks.map((mark, index) => <Marker key={index} position={mark} />)}
```

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Circle } from "react-google-maps";

```
const Map = withScriptjs(
    withGoogleMap(props => (
        <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={12}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
            onClick={e => props.onMapClick(e)}
        >
            {props.marks.map((mark, index) => (
                <Circle
                    key={index}
                    center={mark}
                    radius={1000}
                    options={{
                        strokeColor: "#66009a",
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: `#66009a`,
                        fillOpacity: 0.35,
                        zIndex: 1
                    }}
                />
            ))}
        </GoogleMap>
    ))
);

class ReportsPage extends Component {
    state = {
        marks: []
    };

    setMark = e => {
        this.setState({ marks: [...this.state.marks, e.latLng] });
    };

    deleteMarkS = () => {
        this.setState({
            marks: []
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { marks } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.deleteMark}>DELETE MARKS</button>
                <Map
                    googleMapURL="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR GOOGLE MAPS KEY]"
                    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
                    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    onMapClick={this.setMark}
                    marks={marks}
                />;
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ReportsPage;
```